# A question about an expoential function

Tags: approximation, exponential-function

I got an exponential function as follows
$\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$

Does anyone know how to approximate such a function in a simpler term? Many thanks!

Comment: Taylor knows how.

Answer (score 1):

You could write out $e^{-x}$ in a power series.  If we have $e^{-x} = 1 - x +\frac{x^2}{2} - \cdots$, then your expression becomes a little simple.  I'm not sure if that's what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Buy using $e^{-x}=\sum_k \frac{(-1)^k x^k}{k!}$, it will result in an expression like $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k x^{k-1}}{k!}$, which is even more complicated. I was hoping to approximate such a function with an expression with just one or two simpler terms.

Comment: But you can truncate this and bound the error.